# OWA on IE8 cannot access local shared folder, error "network access is denied"

Tags: windows-7, permissions, network-shares, internet-explorer-8, outlook-web-access

Here's the setup:

I'm connecting to an exchange server via OWA (Outlook Web Access) in IE 8 on Windows 7. Everything works as it is supposed to, except that I cannot access a local shared drive when attaching a file to a mail message. I get the error message "network access is denied"

The local shared drive is simply a drive letter mapped to a specific location on my C: drive. E.g. "H:" => "c:\path\to\files" (I can attach files if I navigate through to the C: to "\path\to\files").

This seemed like it would be a simple permissions problem (right now the shared drive is owned by my user account (full permissions) and "Authenticated Users" has full rights also.

I tried adding various accounts and groups to provide access with no improvement (and to test, I close IE, make the user account changes and re-open IE). I even added "ANONYMOUS LOGON" user with full rights (very briefly) and it makes no difference.

So I have a couple of hypotheses and am looking for assistance in resolving this:

1) Perhaps there's some underlying service running and I need to log all the way out of Windows and back on in order to have my permission changes take effect?

2) This is not in fact a drive/share permissions problem, but something else. For the life of me I can't think of what it might be.

Any assistance or ideas in debugging would be great!

Comment: I'm still experiencing this problem, and to top it off, it happens on a new laptop (still win 7). So this is a fairly generic problem, fwiw. Help!

Comment: This is a 'me too' comment… In my case it's upload to SharePoint. What's strange is that when you press Ctrl-O to open a new web page and click on Browser to locate a file on the local file system, network drives are access correctly.